# Explain Like I'm Five - Website Retrieves File, Manipulates File, and Returns File

Tags: http, web, server

This is a super general question - what does the infrastructure of website/app look like that can:

1. Accept a user inputted file (.xlsx, .png, etc.)
2. Take that input and manipulate the file (such as adding a row in excel)
3. Return the file

I can't really wrap my head around this web concept. For example - https://pixlr.com/x/ (or any other website that takes a file, changes it, and gives it back to you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website can take a file from a user through a form, when clicking a submit button it makes a HTTP POST request that includes all of the file data.

The server hosting the website receives the request and extracts the data from it. This data can come in pieces (many requests), or over a stable connection directly (websockets). The data will look like a binary file, which is a file made of lots of characters that depends on the data itself.

Once received by the server it is changed locally, much like you would do by hand such as editing an image in Adobe, but instead programmatically, before sending it back to the client (the browser that uploaded the file) via one of the earlier methods.